# How to use this parameter inside a javascript object that calling a function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function `calcAge()` inside a javascript object. `calcAge()` function required a parameter birthYr. If i use `calcAge(1998)` this is working. But i want this birthYr parameter will be the own element of that object, But this is Showing Undefined. How can i do this? and also i can i get person object retiredIn element with the returned value of that function? why person object always showing retiredIn element as a Function? i want to get it as a function output. How to do this?

I Try,

```js
function calcAge(birthYr) {
  return 2020 - birthYr;
}
var person = {
  birthYear: 1998,
  age: calcAge(this.birthYear), //This is Showing Undefined
  retiredIn: function () {
    return 65 - this.age; //So this returns a NaN
  },
  name: "Monir",
  job: "Teacher"
};
console.log(person.birthYear); //This is Ok when i am trying to call it from outside!

console.log(person);
```

[image]

Comment: this.birthYear is not instanciated, when you are initialising the person object.   (add console.log(bYr)  to your calcAge

Comment: explain more with solution please,

Comment: youre creating an object var person = { ..  so the this variable doesnt yet exist, until after the creation has completed, so cal age cannot use it until after object has initialised

Comment: yes, Thank You, Got the Solution!

Comment: Use Arrow function `()=>{}` instead of regular function, your issue will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the definition for person does not refer to person.

You haven't finished defining the object yet.

so you can write

```
function calcAge(birthYr) {
  return 2020 - birthYr;
}
var person = {};
person.birthYear= 1998;
person.age = calcAge(person.birthYear);
person.retiredIn = function () {
  return 65 - person.age; 
};
person.name = "Monir";
person.job = "Teacher";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) function instead.

```js
function calcAge(birthYr) {
  return 2020 - birthYr;
}
var person = {
  birthYear: 1998,
  get age() {
    return calcAge(this.birthYear)
  },
  retiredIn: function() {
    return 65 - this.age;
  },
  name: "Monir",
  job: "Teacher"
};
console.log(person.birthYear); //This is Ok when i am trying to call it from outside!

console.log(person);
```